# Can you normalize/standardize binary variables in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, normalization

A dataframes output column is under binary variables (0 for no disease. 1 for disease). There are 30x as many with 0 than 1 so my data visualizations are not to scale. Is there a way to standardize/normalize binary variables.

Here's an example of a data visualization that shows the imbalance.

[image: 1]

Comment: How do you want to "normalize" the count? You need to think about what you really want to show.

Comment: Currently, there are 30x as many patients with 0 than 1. How can I scale it to reflect a scaled graph?

Comment: What do you want your y axis to represent?

Comment: you can have a second y axis on right side with a different scale to make 1s more significant.

Comment: @matszwecja my y-axis is the binary variable/ count of 0 and 1.

Comment: I'd instead calculate number of samples, and represent how much % does each BMI category represent. So for example Underweight - 2% of 0s, 1% of 1s, Normal - 10% of 0s, 5% of 1s, etc. This way you can have single scale with directly comparable values.

Comment: @PiyushDivyankar how do I make that different scale?

Comment: If you want the ratio of diseased persons per BMI you can try something like `df.groupby("BMI").value_counts(normalize=True)`; another way would be to group by `"FBSS"` and count `"BMI"`. However, you lose information so adding a second scale would be better in this case